# How to get sensor fixture contact position

Tags: libgdx

I use LibGDX and I have a moving solid object (`Fixture B`) and a sensor object (`Fixture A`).

In my `ContactListener` I can check if a solid object and a sensor collide, but I can't tell where the first contact point was (I need to know that point, for using it as center point on the next phase).

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact)
{
  Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
  Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();
  LogMessage("World points: "+contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints().length);
  float contactX = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[0].x; //always 0.0
  float contactY = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[0].y; //always 0.0
  LogMessage("Contact X: "+contactX);
  LogMessage("Contact Y: "+contactY);
}
```

Unfortunately, this manifold does not contain any collision point, as one of the fixtures is a sensor. I'm pretty sure they wouldn't miss the implementation of such an important task as *sensor contact point detection*, I just couldn't find the proper method yet.

Is there any built-in method to detect the contact point?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setUserData("region1") on fixture in the two bodies

```
//Class platform
b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("region1");

//Class Player
b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("foot");
```

and in Contact Listener check if the contact was in that region like this:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    if(fixA.getUserData() == "region1" || fixB.getUserData() == "region1"){
        Fixture foot = fixA.getUserData() == "foot" ? fixA : fixB;
        Fixture object = foot == fixA ? fixB : fixA;
        //
        Gdx.app.log("foot touched","region1");
    }
```

Updated 11/05/16

understood. You are doing correctly

i did a simple example to check:

[the collision points and mouse detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RK06.jpg)

but try to check if your fixture has density. if you are creating a EdgeShape for example, it will not be detected

Comment: You misunderstood my question: I need to know the _exact collision point_ not to determine if the object and the sensor collide. I already have that.